# Facebook Feed Dialog with game images and description below

Tags: java, android, facebook

I want to achieve Facebook Integration in my app.  At this point of time, I have the login and post to wall functionality, but the wall post I have is only like the simple wall post.

I want to achieve [this](http://www.google.com.ph/imgres?um=1&hl=en&biw=1366&bih=667&tbm=isch&tbnid=xCl4384Fay8Y3M%3a&imgrefurl=http://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/feed/&docid=uMhYJ90KunqGnM&imgurl=https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/feed_post_send.jpg&w=583&h=290&ei=qWz-Ua-IFumViAe4pICYCg&zoom=1&ved=1t:3588,r:4,s:0,i:87&iact=rc&page=1&tbnh=158&tbnw=319&start=0&ndsp=16&tx=76&ty=26). Just like in every game, they have this kind of facebook feed..

This is the current code I have..

```
package com.example.facebooktrial;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.facebook.android.AsyncFacebookRunner;
import com.facebook.android.DialogError;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook;
import com.facebook.android.Facebook.DialogListener;
import com.facebook.android.FacebookError;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class AndroidFacebookConnectActivity extends Activity {
    Button btnFbLogin;
    Button btnPostToWall;


    // Your Facebook APP ID
    private static String APP_ID = "593769430655402"; // Replace your App ID here

    // Instance of Facebook Class
    private Facebook facebook;
    private AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner;
    String FILENAME = "AndroidSSO_data";
    private SharedPreferences mPrefs;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnFbLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFbLogin);
        btnPostToWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFbPost);

        facebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);

        btnFbLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    loginToFacebook();
                }
        });
        btnPostToWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                postToWall();
            }
        });


    }
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void loginToFacebook() {
        mPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        String access_token = mPrefs.getString("access_token", null);
        long expires = mPrefs.getLong("access_expires", 0);

        if (access_token != null) {
            facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        }

        if (expires != 0) {
            facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
        }

        if (!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
            facebook.authorize(this,
                    new String[] { "email", "publish_stream" },
                    new DialogListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCancel() {
                            // Function to handle cancel event
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                            // Function to handle complete event
                            // Edit Preferences and update facebook acess_token
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
                            editor.putString("access_token",
                                    facebook.getAccessToken());
                            editor.putLong("access_expires",
                                    facebook.getAccessExpires());
                            editor.commit();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(DialogError error) {
                            // Function to handle error

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError fberror) {
                            // Function to handle Facebook errors

                        }

                    });
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void postToWall() {
        // post on user's wall.
        facebook.dialog(this, "feed", new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that you're currently using to generate the wall (as concise as possible).

Comment: I already edited the post. Thanks

Comment: @SteveP. Please help me... I need to do this badly.. because it is part of my thesis..

Comment: Sorry, I'd like to help, but am not familiar with the API, so I would need to look it all up--something that I'd normally do, but not today.  I have a major responsibility relating to my coursework also.  I'll look into this sometime later tonight or tomorrow if no one else has provided you with anything.

Comment: hmmm.. okay thanks.. just comment here when you have found the solution if no one else provides.. I'm looking forward to your help..

Comment: You can not modify the post using the Feed Dialog (its design is by default). I think the feeds you are looking for are the [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) `Actions`. [link here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/)

Comment: But the image you have attached, is just a normal feed with a `picture` `description`. You can change these parameters as you wish. You can see the list of parameters [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/).

Comment: Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. Just make use of a Bundle where you'll store all the necessary information like the picture, name, link and so on.. After that, include that bundle in the Facebook dialog as an argument..

```
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public void postToWall() {
        // post on user's wall.

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("name", "Check it out, I am playing FLIP game!");
        params.putString("caption", "Come on FLIP with me");
        params.putString("description", "FLIP!");
        params.putString("picture", "http://www.rawk.com/media/images/uploaded/products/2099/flip-hkd-black-complete-skateboard.3043.full.jpg");
        facebook.dialog(this, "feed",params, new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
            }
        });

    }
```